# c++ creating object of second class in the constructor of first class - multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, constructor, qthread

I have two classes one and two . Both run threads. class Two is to thread a function declared in class one . this is done by calling it in the run method of the second class. I am trying to call/start the thread Two in constructor of one so that both these threads run together.
i get scope error .due to missing syntax. the code is given below

```
#include <QtGui>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class One:public QThread
{
public:
    One()
    {
        Two b; // error: 'Two' was not declared in this scope error: expected ';' before 'b'
        b.start();//error: 'b' was not declared in this scope|
        b.wait();
    };
    void run();
    void beep();
};
void One::run()
{

}
void One::beep()
{

}
class Two:public QThread
{
public:
    Two()
    {

    };
    void run();
};
void Two::run()
{
    One a;
    a.beep();
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    One a;
    a.start();
    a.wait();
    return(0);

}
```

The errors as given in comments next to the code are .

> error: 'Two' was not declared in this
> scope
>
> error: expected ';' before 'b'
>
> error: 'b' was not declared in this
> scope

What syntax am i missing ?

Comment: the solution to the actual point of this program was provided by Erik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230444/c-qthread-starting-2-threads-concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error are caused by compiler trying to instantiate class/type that hasn't been declared.

You should split your declaration and implementation into separate file, preferably the widely used .h and .cpp format. Then include the type's header in cpp where you need them.

Comment: Yes, that removed the build error,What worked for this problem was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230444/c-qthread-starting-2-threads-concurrently)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I may be missing something, but it seems like your problem is that definition of One doesn't see even the declaration of two; move the declarations into the header file e.g.

class One:public QThread
{
public:
    One();
    void run();
    void beep();
};

and then in .cpp:
One::One()
{
    Two b; 
    b.start();
    b.wait();
};

similarly with Two.
This will make it build; I won't comment on it in general as I'm not very familiar with QT