# c++ qthread starting 2 threads concurrently

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, concurrency, qthread

I have two threads One and Two. defined by their respective classes in the header file.I want to start the second thread when the first thread is started.  creating and starting the second thread in the constructor of the first produced unexpected result.
my header file **"header.h"**

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER
#include <QtGui>
class One:public QThread
{
public:
    One();
    void run();

};

class Two:public QThread
{
public:
    Two();
    void run();
};
#endif
```

my class file **"main.cpp"**

```
#include "header.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

One::One()
{
/* the output just hangs at thread two and does not get to thread one run */
Two b;
b.start();
b.wait();

}
void One::run()
{
    cout<<"One run\n";
    int i=0;
    for(;;)
    {

        i++;
        cout<<"+++ "<<i<<endl;
        if(i==10)
            break;
        sleep(3);
    }
}

Two::Two()
{

}
void Two::run()
{

    cout<<"Two run\n";
    int i=0;
    for(;;)
    {

        i--;
        cout<<"----- "<<i<<endl;
        sleep(3);
    }
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    One a;
   // Two b;
    a.start();
   // b.start();
   a.wait();
   // b.wait();
    return(0);

}
```

This is the working code of how i expect the output to run.

> **Edit: changed the code so that now
>   both the threads are properly
>   independent**
>
> **How do i start the second thread along with the first thread, without explicitly  calling two in main i.e .**

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
     One a;
    Two b;
    a.start();
    b.start();
    a.wait();
    b.wait();
   return(0);
}
```

> The invoking and handling of thread two should be done by thread one..

Comment: currently what i have is two independently running threads which are started separately. what i am trying to do is to have the second thread be invoked when the thread one is started.

Comment: And that doesn't make sense. The thread's invoked when you start it. You cannot call from one thread *context* to another, even though you can call from one thread *object* to another

Comment: @Erick i have changed the code. removing the calling of one thread context to another. I have tried invoking the thread two in constructor of thread one is this wrong? as i cant seem to see the thread one's run output .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you've perhaps misunderstood some threading concepts. It sounds like you want to start two threads, then from one thread context make a function call to another thread context, which is not how threads work.

When you start these two threads, they execute independently of each other. They can share access to data, but you can't intertwine their execution the way you seem to want to. If you want one thread to perform something on request of another, you have two decide two things:

- Which mechanism to use for signaling the request from one thread to the other
- Whether the requesting thread should stop and wait for a "receipt" or just happily continue while the other thread does what it was asked to.

A *very* simple (and not really safe, this is just illustrating the logics) mechanism for doing this would be using two bools to signal a request, e.g:

```
Thread one starts                         | Thread two starts
Thread one works                          | Thread two loops checking a `bool DoSomething;`
Thread one sets bool DoSomething          | 
Thread one loops waiting for DidSomething | Thread two beeps
                                          | Thread two sets DidSomething
Thread one continues working              |
```

The thing to notice is that there's no "calls" in between thread contexts. The two threads execute simultaneously, and communicate by using data (the two bools).

In real world multithreading, you have to worry about simultaneous access to data. What would e.g. happen if two threads, at the same time on a dual-core machine, tried to append data to the same list. Both threads may see the same "end of list pointer", both would create a new entry, both would update the "end of list pointer". But one of the changes will overwrite the other, and in best case you'd have some lost data and a memory leak, in worst case you'd have a crash.

This is where you use a "mutual exclusion" mechanism: each thread will, before accessing such a shared resource as the list, get hold of a mutex. A mutex is constructed in such a way that only one thread at a time can "own" it. If thread one happens to acquire the mutex first, it'll proceed to do its list update, and then let go of the mutex. In the meantime, the other threads attempt to acquire the mutex will simply sit there, the Mutex::acquire() call will not return until thread one is done with the mutex. If both threads behave nicely, and acquire the mutex before accessing the shared list, the simultaneous update described above will not happen, and the list will be perfectly valid after both threads have updated it.

In response to comments:

You cannot start the two threads simultaneously. The closest approximation would be to create and start Two from within One::run:

```
void One::run()
{
    Two b;
    b.start();
    cout<<"One run\n";
    int i=0;
    for(;;)
    {

        i++;
        cout<<"+++ "<<i<<endl;
        if(i==10)
            break;
        sleep(3);
    }
    b.wait();
}
```

Comment: Setting bools as flags is not safe without proper memory barriers or locking. In Qt you'd be better served by using cross-thread signals.

Comment: You may also want to read for *condition variables*. They allow a thread to block until some condition is signalled by another thread. It is an alternative to an empty `while` loop which will take unneccesary CPU time. See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwaitcondition.html for details.

Comment: No it's not, thus the "*very* simple" phrase. The intent was to illustrate the logics of communication in between threads as opposed to the authors desire to call between contexts.

Comment: @Erik, it's dangerous to teach flawed synchronized protocols to beginners like that - they might try to implement them without the proper barriers, and end up creating a broken program. Either teach using locks and condition variables, or include a discussion on the importance of barriers.

Comment: @bdonlan: Post's edited now explicitly stating that the bools are unsafe. A complete threading course is way beyond the scope of such a question though, this should be enough to get him started.

Comment: @Erick Ok so in the example caling beep from Two is wrong. i should just declare beep in Two and use it ?

Comment: Calling obj.beep() within Two's method will execute beep *in thread Two's execution context*. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer, I would suggest posting a new question, explaining in detail what you want to accomplish - rather than just explaining how you want to do it (which in this case makes no sense...)

Comment: @Erick .. that is part of what i wanted.the beep function is meant to run in a separate thread i can declare it in two or one . didn't think it was an issue.  What i am trying to do is to start the second thread concurrently the primary purpose of my posting the question.

Comment: You are starting them as concurrently as you can, with `a.start(); b.start();`

Comment: it works when i call a.start();b.start() in the main. i do not want to explicitly call b.start() in the main .

Comment: Then do it in `One::run()`: `Two b; b.start();` and before `One::run()` exits, do `b.wait();`

Comment: yes thank you can you add/edit this as part of your main answer this is the part i am looking for.